# How I can split String on (:) but not time

Tags: java, regex

I have String (myname:myemail: 12:30:00) or (myname:myemail: 12:30:00.3) and another string (myname: myemail : myphone), so how I can split  on : and keep time as it.

Thanks

Comment: Read about [`String#split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) with `limit`.

Comment: Just think about what makes the different parts unique/stand out

Comment: What about `myname:myemail: 12:30:61`?

Comment: I have different strings but some of these strings come with time

Comment: @user3455386 split with colon and space?

Comment: @RealSkeptic I don't see what's not clear in this question.

Comment: @user3455386 post all the possibilities along with the output you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split like this:

```
String[] t = s.split( "(?<!\\d):(?!\\d)" );
```

Or if time is alway dd:dd:dd (double digits)

```
String[] t = s.split( "(?<!\\d\\d):(?!\\d\\d)" );
```

Comment: i think this `"(?<!\\d):(?!\\d)"` would be fine..

Comment: @AvinashRaj Well, I was thinking of s.th. like "The match ended 3:0 at 15:22:22" ;-) - but that's probably not an issue.

Comment: i think he described the formats.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want this:
myname
myemail
12:30:00

```
String string = "myname:myemail: 12:30:00";
String firstSplit[] = string.split(" ");
String secondSplit[] = firstSplit[0].split(":");

String time = firstSplit[1];
String name = secondSplit[0];
String email = secondSplit[1];
```

Or you can work with split(String regex, int limit):

```
String string = "myname:myemail: 12:30:00";
String split[] = string.split(":", 3);

String name = split[0];
String email = split[1];
String time = split[2];
```

Comment: You are assuming very special contents. That's not good coding. -1

Comment: @laune what exactly do you mean by special content?

Comment: Two sequences of letters with colons and then one space and then the time. What about "12:30:00 foo:bar"? Or "my name:my age:12:30:00"?